# How to fix this error The selector “app-component” did not match any elements in angular 2.0 application

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am getting an `error` in browser console when I click on the browser refresh button after running my `Angular 2` application. It doesn't stop `Angular 2` routing from one `component` to the other. Aside from the `error` it is working fine. But I want my `app` to run with 0 `warnings` or `errors` in the `console`.

This is the `error` I am getting in my browser `console`.

> Error in ./t class t_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: The
>   selector "app-component" did not match any elements. ORIGINAL
>   EXCEPTION: The selector "app-component" did not match any elements.

How can I clear this `error`?

Comment: Does this error only appear when you refresh the screen after the app is running fine?

Comment: it looks like you used <app-component> tag some where in your template but  your component does not have the selector 'app-component'. check that your AppComponent have selector named properly.

Comment: @wuno, yes i mean to say its intermittently occurs, and if i again click on refresh button its run the application without any error in console.

Comment: @Mehari, no i used <app-component> only in index.html and in app.component.ts have selector as  a 'selector: 'app-component'

Comment: Oh wait I think I misunderstood you. So you are not getting errors when you refresh the page? You mean in the console it has an error and thats it? Not a 404? or the content not loading in the page when you refresh it the first time?

Comment: @VinodPharande is my answer does not help you I strongly suggest you add a lot more information about your program. Your question is basically just showing an error and saying how do I fix this. That is typically pretty close to impossible for anyone to actually answer without seeing at least a small portion of your code. Also it would be nice to know what your using in your application. For example the back end etc. I would be surprised if you are only using angular2 which is all we can gather at this point from your question.

Comment: @wuno, when i refresh the page then i am getting this error (its not happened in specific time that means some time while refreshing first time and some times even if i tried multiple time refresh then this error comes in console), but not always its an intermittent error, after this if i clicked on browser refresh button again then its working fine. so its not about 404.

Comment: @wuno, fornt end: Angular 2.0+typescipt, back end: node.js with express js. For template/view engine for nods js we used ejs(Embedded JavaScript templates) and code is,  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I was bootstrapping other components n AppModule. Only AppComponent needs to be bootstrapped. Remove all other declarations from the bootstrap array, so your @NgModule looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  ...
})
```